# Continuously re-execute a command when it finishes in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to figure out a simple way to keep re-executing a command whenever it finishes, for any reason (error or otherwise).

What would be the best way to approach this?

**EDIT:** I wasn't clear enough before. I need the next execution to **wait** until the previous one finishes.

**EDIT 2:** Almost all answers work great. I mistakenly thought most answers would either fork the process or re-execute it just once, neither of which is wanted.

Comment: You still aren't clear. It'd help if you mentioned what program you're executing.

Comment: -1 This question does not show any research effort, as the user commented that answers didn't work instead of actually trying to do what they suggest.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This creates an infinite loop, executing `command` over and over again.

```bsh
while :
do
    command
done
```

Comment: Please see the edit to the original question. I need to keep re-executing it over and over again, not just once.

Comment: @calcifer This answer works quite well. There's something unusual about your program that none of the four users answering so far anticipated and you failed to mention it.

Comment: @calcifer this is an infinite loop. it keeps repeating until the end of time (well, until the script is terminated anyways)

Comment: My bad, I thought this (and all the other answers) will either fork the process or re-execute it just once, neither of which is wanted. So yes, this answer works. Thanks.

Comment: one line version: `while true; do echo 'Hit CTRL+C'; sleep 1; done`, thanks to https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-infinite-loop/

Answer (score 118):

The `watch` command will repeat a command forever with an interval specified:

```
watch -n0 <command>
```

Setting `-n` to zero effectively puts the interval at nothing (I think it is really .1 seconds).

`watch` also has the added benefits of aligning the output so visual changes can be seen easily, and has a switch to highlight changes from the last run.

[Reference: the watch man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch):

> watch runs command repeatedly, displaying its output (the first screenfull). This allows you to watch the program output change over time. By default, the program is run every 2 seconds; use -n or --interval to specify a different interval.
>
> watch will run until interrupted.

Comment: Please see the edit to the original question.

Comment: All of the answers so far do this, including this one.  Linux won't fork unless you specifically ask it to.

Comment: I can't see any output using this method.

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian Are you saying if you do `watch ls` in a directory that contains files, you don't get anything?

Comment: actually I was doing it with offlineimap.

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian  So the approach works, you just don't get expected output from the specific thing you are doing.  Sounds like a different problem

Comment: i dont see the continous output. so if i run watch echo 3 i am expecting to see a bunch of 3's printed but i only see one execution.

Comment: @j2emanue You are seeing multiple executions, but `watch` clears the screen each time.  If you just want to loop a command, put a while loop around it.

Comment: @Paul your right. i just confirmed it. it keeps updating the same line. thanks

Answer (score 20):

A simple solution would be:

```
yourcommand; !#
```

`;` separates commands, allowing for multiple commands in one line ([Bash: Lists](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists))

`!#` tells bash to "repeat everything I have written so far in this line" ([Bash: Event-Designators](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Event-Designators))

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I need to keep re-executing it over and over again, not just once.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was looking for it, especially since `yourcommand; !!` does not actually work with commands on the same line, however, `!#` seems to do. Cheers!

Comment: `; !#` didn't work on ZSH, it just expands the statement essentially cloning it, it doesn't trigger it

Answer (score 7):

You can plan ahead during command execution (provided it isn't interactive) and enter `!!` which will execute the previous command again. This works e.g. during `ping -c 5`.

---

You can also define a function in `bash`:

```
function repeat { "$@"; "$@"; }
```

To persist it, store it in `~/.bashrc`.

Then, you can run your command like this:

```
repeat ping -c5 heise.de
```

If it's a specific command you want to repeatedly execute (and not e.g. *any* command), you can replace `"$@"` in that snippet with your actual command, and name the function e.g. `repeat_ping` instead.

---

To make it an infinite loop, you can do what @Dennis suggests. I recommend you add a waiting period if you intend to use this in an interactive shell, like this:

```
function repeat { while 1 ; do "$@" ; sleep 1 ; done; }
```

Otherwise it's rather inconvenient to abort this infinite loop using `Ctrl-Z`.

Comment: Please see the edit to the original question.

Comment: @calcifer These executions wait until the program call returns. Does your program detach from the shell and return before it quits?

Comment: My bad, I thought this (and all the other answers) will either fork the process or re-execute it just once, neither of which is wanted. So yes, this answer works. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Give a `while` loop a boolean condition such as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do

    do_something && wait

done
```

This will execute over and over until bash receives a signal to terminate the process. Usually in the form of `ctrl+c`.

You can also use the `watch` command to run a script repeatedly as well. For instance a simple clock in your bash terminal using `watch` could look like:

```
$ watch -t -n1 date +%T
```

The `-t` option tells `watch` to not display a title of the process it is running. This gives you a clean output of only the command that is being repeated. The `-n1` option tells watch to repeat every `n` seconds. In this case, `-n1` will be intervals of `1` second. Then the `date +%T` command shows the time at the time of command completion. Doing this command will give you an active clock in your terminal.

And then one more method that isn't in any of the other answers would be an infinite function call.

```
do_something() { do_something }; do_something && wait
```

This is essentially the same as the boolean `while` loop only using recursive function calls.

(edit)
For keeping your machine's resources in mind, I have added the `&& wait` so that each time a process is run, the loops will "wait" until that process finishes with exit status 0 before the next iteration. This is useful in an interactive shell script.

Comment: There is a `while` loop example but it isn't using a boolean `true` syntax. There is a `watch` example but it doesn't give many useful syntax. I am expounding on these for whomever it may help. I wanted to give some practical usefulness to these. The `while` loop boolean can also be `false` and not execute until an untrue condition is met. It is quite handy.

Comment: @Spittin'IT Added a method that is not used in other answers for your convenience.

Comment: Fair enough and I understand... I was just commenting as I went thru the review module but nice edit and follow up!!

Comment: How does `if` keep re-executing?

Comment: Good point Kamil. Forgot to make it recursive lol. Fixed in edit using a function calling itself in the `if` statement.

Comment: This `if` example seems over-complicated: (1) the `if` itself adds nothing and can be omitted; (2) the function does nothing more than calling itself. It's not clear where to put some custom code. How about `run_me() { do_something; do_something_more; run_me; }; run_me`?

Comment: The if statement adds just another method. Nothing more, nothing less.The question asks for methods of recursion and they have been given. How practical or useful you might believe it is, or isn't, is irrelevant.

Comment: Because it seems an issue, I have removed the `if` statement and just added a recursive function call method instead. It is useful as I use it fairly often, personally, in my own scripts.

Comment: +1 for the `&& wait` I was looking for a way for bash to detect that the command ended successfully before running it again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm feeling saucy today.

Read from one of the infinite streams and pipe it to `xargs`

```
cat /dev/zero | xargs --null echo hello there
```

If you need to put a little bit of a break in there you will likely need to execute `sh`

```
cat /dev/zero | xargs --null sh -c "echo hello there; sleep 3"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another method I use to repeat a command in bash. This might sound silly to some as it does not involve writing a script and might be known to many. But I think it is worth mentioning as it is quick and beginner-friendly, in the sense that there is not much syntax to remember. I've only tested this in gnome-terminal of Ubuntu and other terminals might not support this.

1. Enter the command in terminal once.
2. Select the command including newline character with mouse.
3. Copy the selection using Ctrl-Insert or using context menu (usually accessed with right click).
4. Use Shift-Insert to paste as many times as you want to run the command.

You don't have to wait to paste until each command finishes. The pasted commands get into a queue and they execute one after another.